# I need to connect my Pi to a piece of hardware via fiber that only responds to rs232 commands

Tags: pi-3, ethernet

I have an Ethernet to fiber converter that I can interface to the PI but I am not sure how to or if its even possible to setup the ethernet connection with the fiber convertor to pull data via rs232 commands.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to use the Ethernet to fibre converter - the signalling is totally different.

RS/232 is a standard for connection not for data structure.

You can get serial to fibre converters but care must be taken you match connectors and standard (RS/232 is not the same as RS/422 etc). A Google search for `Fiber Optic Media Converter` Will turn up local suppliers for you who maybe able to advise you on the connector type and fibre type.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong terms. Normally we communicate to the unit via a serial connection through hyperterm from our laptop. The standard 8-n-1 9600 baud. The fiber cable uses a LC type connector though a fiber converter. I'd like to come up with a low cost independent solution using an existing PI that could be left on the unit instead of a laptop for long term monitoring.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as there is no such thing as "rs232 commands" NO.

You can get RS232 serial converters and USB serial interfaces with pseudo RS232 levels. (No computer manufactured in the last 20 years actually uses ±15V RS232 levels).

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm changing gears and moving forward with a rs 232 to fiber converter. Hopefully the usb on the pi2 has sufficient current to drive it.